# Is this a correct question?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

This is an exam question in functional analysis which for me doesn't make sense the way it is written. I am asking you if you agree with me on the modifications that needs to be done in the question.

Question: Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed linear spaces and $T: X\rightarrow Y$ a linear operator. Recall that the dual $X^*$ of $X$ is the space of bounded linear functionals on $X$ with the norm $||\phi ||=sup\{|\phi (x) | :x\in X \textrm{ and } ||x||\leq 1 \}$. (Similarly for $Y$). Define $T^*:Y^*\rightarrow X^*$ by $[T^*(\phi )](x)=\phi (Tx)$ for $\phi \in Y^*$. Show that $||T^*||\leq ||T||$.

My comments to the question: Define $T^*:Y^*\rightarrow X^*$ by $[T^*(\phi )](x)=\phi (Tx)$ for $\phi \in Y^*$. For me this doesn't make sense, but I understand it if one drops the $x$, i.e. $T^*:Y^*\rightarrow X^*$ by $T^*(\phi )=\phi T$ since then the domain and codomain makes sense, what worries me with the notation above is that $[T^*(\phi )](x)$ has no meaning since $\phi$ is not defined on $X$ and furthermore $\phi (Tx)$ is a scalar and not an element of $X^*$. Furthermore, I feel a bit ackward about talking about $||T||$ when $T$ is not assumed to be bounded, so I have assumed that. Is this correct or could we talk about $||T||$ in some general way when $T$ is not bounded? With this change of the question I understand the solution to it, I have added the indexes on the norms, so it is possible to follow my argument: $|| T^*(\phi )||_{X^*}=||\phi T||_{X^*}$ $=sup \{|\phi T x| : ||x||_{X}\leq 1 \}$ $\leq sup \{||\phi ||_{Y^*} || T ||_{B(X,Y)}||x||_{X} : ||x||\leq 1 \}$ $= ||\phi||_{Y^*} || T ||_{B(X,Y)}.$ Hence $|| T^*(\phi )||_{X^*}$ $\leq ||\phi||_{Y^*} || T ||_{B(X,Y)}$. Now, $||T^*||=sup \{|| T^*\phi ||_{X^*} : ||\phi ||_{Y^*}\leq 1 \}$ and hence letting $||\phi ||_{Y^*}\leq 1$ in the inequality $|| T^*(\phi )||_{X^*}$ $\leq ||\phi||_{Y^*} || T ||_{B(X,Y)}$ showes that  $||T^*||\leq ||T||$.

What do you think about the question and the suggested modifications to it?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the problem as it is phrased. The only thing is that it forgets to say $T$ is bounded. But that should be clear since it mentions $\|T\|$.

Answer (score 1):

The question is correctly stated (but boundedness has to be assumed). If $\phi\in Y^*$, then, by definition, $T\phi\in X^*$ and hence $[T\phi](x)$ makes sense. Also $Tx\in Y$ and hence, $\phi(Tx)$ makes sense. The way $T^*\phi = \phi\circ T$ is also ok.